# How to set up a data warehouse using mysql

Tags: mysql, csv, data-warehouse

I have been trying to set up a data warehouse using ralph kimballs technique but I am having difficulty actually understanding how to load data into my tables. I have a sales_filev1.csv  that contains the columns:

CUST_CITY_NM
CUST_STREET_ADD
CUST_POSTAL_CD
CUST_STATE_CD
CUST_NM
CUST_NO
CUST_PHONE_NO
PROD_CAT_CD
PROD_LN_CD
PROD_NM
PROD_PACKAGE_SIZE_NO
SLS_PROMO_IN
SLS_QTY_NO
SLS_UNIT_PRICE_AM
STORE_CITY_NM
STORE_ESTABLISH_DT
STORE_ID
STORE_LVL_CD
STORE_MGR_NM
STORE_MGR_PHONE_NO
STORE_NM
STORE_NO
STORE_POSTAL_CD
STORE_STATE_CD
STORE_STREET_AD
SALES_DT

Then I have a CUST_LOOKUP.csv containing 
CUST_NO
CUST_ID
CUST_INCOME_AM
CUST_CD

Then the last file is a product lookup: 
PROD_NM
PROD_SKU_NO
SLS_UNIT_COST_AM
PROD_INTRO_DT
PROD_ID

I understand that I need to do have a sales_fact table as well. However, would my sales_filev1 not be the sales fact since it contains all of the information about the customers, store and products purchased and when? Then I would just use a join and insert to add the data together?

Comment: Your sales fact will be based upon sales-filev1, probably row to row. But you have to move the product info on the product dim table, the store info on the store dim table and so on. I would load the three csv file in "stage" tables and load dims and facts with SQL. PS: Try to read the kimball book cover to cover, it will be time good spent.

Comment: Slightly off-topic; There are a couple of great tools you could use to prototype your dwh.  [Power BI](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/) and [Power Pivot](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Power-Pivot-Add-in-a9c2c6e2-cc49-4976-a7d7-40896795d045) (both by Microsoft) provide the ablitlity to quickly build and test data model designs.  Whatever tool you use; prototyping is great way to get your head around how the finished product will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to model your data dimensionally (if you are going to use a star schema) and decide the grain of your data, determine the measures that will go into the fact table(s) and the attributes that will reside in the dimension table(s).

A datawarehouse is not joining all the data you have together in one table. It is optimal for storage and reporting.

Have a read of [Dimensional Modelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_modeling) and perhaps purchase the excellent book by [Ralph Kimball's DWH Toolkit](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Data-Warehouse-Toolkit-Complete-Dimensional/dp/0471200247).